# Measuring a mixture of density operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, density-operator

I am trying to understand a step in the proof of the [Holevo bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holevo's_theorem) on page 534 of Nielsen and Chuang.

The context is that there are density operators $\rho_1, \ldots, \rho_n$ and [POVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM) operators $\{E_y\}$. I'm trying to see why after measuring, we have $$p(y|x) = \mathrm{tr}(\rho_x E_y)$$

I understand the simpler case where if we had a state $| \psi \rangle$ and then measured, then the probability of outcome $m$ would be $p(m) = \langle \psi| E_y | \psi \rangle$. I'm unsure about how to understand the situation when we have a mixture of density operators:

If we write each density operator as $$\rho_x = \sum_i p_{ix} |\psi_{ix}\rangle \langle \psi_{ix}|,$$ then is it true that $$p(y|x) = \sum_i p_{ix} \langle \psi_{ix}| E_y |\psi_{ix}\rangle\ ?$$

Comment: You are not asking whether if you insert the first equation in the first you get the third, are you?  If not, then you should ask the real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantity
 $$p(y|x) = \mathrm{tr}(\rho_x E_y)$$
denotes the probability of getting a click on the measurement outcome encoded by $E_y$, conditioned on the system having been prepared on the state $\rho_x$. This is essentially the introduction (i.e. the definition) of new notation, and as such it does not really need to be justified: you can define whatever you want, and you only really need to justify it afterwards by way of using the quantities you define to say useful things.

However, it does build on a previous foundation: if you prepare the system in a state with density matrix $\rho$ and then measure on the POVM $\{E_m\}$, then the probability of obtaining output $m$ is given by
$$
p(m)=\mathrm{tr}(\rho E_m).
$$
To some extent this is a definition, but it is built on the fact that if $\rho=\sum_j p_j |\psi_j⟩⟨\psi_j|$, i.e. the state is built by preparing the pure states $|\psi_j⟩$ (which don't even need to be orthogonal!) with probabilities $p_j$, then this trace decomposes to
$$
p(m)
=\mathrm{tr}(\rho E_m)
=\sum_j p_j \mathrm{tr}(|\psi_j⟩⟨\psi_j| E_m)
=\sum_j p_j ⟨\psi_j| E_m|\psi_j⟩
,
$$
which is precisely what you would expect it to come to: the convex combination of the probabilities of $E_m$ on each of the $|\psi_j⟩$, weighed by the probability that the given pure state was prepared.

With that in mind, your calculation of this quantity as $p(y|x) = \sum_i p_{ix} \langle \psi_{ix}| E_y |\psi_{ix}\rangle$ given the decomposition of the state as $\rho_x = \sum_i p_{ix} |\psi_{ix}\rangle \langle \psi_{ix}|$ is indeed correct.

Comment: If $p(y|x) = tr(\rho_xE_y)$ is essentially a definition, then why is it a reasonable one? I certainly did not get the impression that the authors were introducing this as a new definition. Btw, this is in Nielsen and Chuang's text on page 534.

Comment: @theQman I don't really understand the question. What else would you propose for the probability I mentioned? Maybe you're just struggling with the concept of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)? That one is tricky enough in its own way but none of what's difficult about it is specific to quantum theory.

Comment: I don't think it's conditional probability that I'm struggling with; it's extending the idea of a measurement of a state to the idea of measurement of a mixture of density operators. I am comfortable in the usual context where we have POVM elements $\{ E_m\}$ and some states $| \psi_i \rangle$, then the probability of getting result $m$ given state $i$ is $p(m|i) = tr(E_m |\psi_i \rangle \langle \psi_i|)$. I think that we should be able to use this to show that $p(y|x) = tr(\rho_x E_y)$ in the above context. Am I wrong about something?

Comment: @theQman I really don't understand what you're confused by. If you prepare the system in the state $\rho$ and then measure on the POVM $\{E_m\}$ then the $m$th outcome will occur with probability $p(m)=\mathrm{tr}(\rho E_m)$. Is that confusing? The expression for $p(x|y)$ is the direct, natural extension to the case where you're conditioning on which state you actually prepared.

Comment: @theQman OK, fair enough. I've updated my answer to expand a bit on that.